# Parse a value from API return message in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, api, laravel

I have an API that I'm retrieving stats from and need to parse out certain information to return in a view.

I've written a curl request to get information I need from the API provied.

```
// create curl resource 
        $ch = curl_init($cdnifybandwidthurl); 

    // sets GET 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET'); // -X      

    // $output contains the output string 
    $bandwidth_usage = curl_exec($ch); 

    // close curl resource to free up system resources 
    curl_close($ch);
```

This request returns a string like this

```
{"resource":"xxxx","datefrom":"2015-07-01",
"dateto":"2015-07-31","origin":"xxx.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
"overall_usage":[[{"timestamp":"2015-07-02 
00:00:00","cached":1739969,"non_cached":340826,"hits":76}]]}
```

What I need to do is return the non_cached amount in a view.  I am having trouble extracting only that amount out of the string.

Answer (score 0):

The overall usage looks like a list of lists to me you have to decide in case there are more items, which one you want.

Your API returns JSON, so I suggest `$obj = json_decode($bandwidth_usage, true)` and access what you need from the lists in here `$obj['overall_usage']` or am I missing the point?

Assuming I`m on track you can in this particular case go ahead with:

```
$obj['overall_usage'][0][0]["non_cached"]
                      ^ first item of first array
                         ^ first item of second array
                            ^ item with key "non_cached"
```

Comment: you are right, but in the overall_usage how do I access the non_cached value and return it in a view?